# GCP log-based alert only if the last message matches two conditions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, logging, alert, stackdriver

I'm trying to create a log-based alert to check if a log message **hasn't** been seen recently.  Additionally, I only want the alert to trigger if the last log message contains a certain string.

Here's an example:

I want to trigger an alert if the last log message contains "alive and kicking" and is more than 20 minutes old.

```
2022-12-29 15:00 i'm alive but inactive.  don't send an alert.
2022-12-29 15:10 i'm alive but inactive.  don't send an alert.
2022-12-29 15:20 i'm alive but inactive.  don't send an alert.
2022-12-29 16:00 i'm alive and kicking.  send an alert if you don't hear from me in the next 20 minutes.
2022-12-29 16:10 i'm alive and kicking.  send an alert if you don't hear from me in the next 20 minutes.
2022-12-29 16:20 i'm alive and kicking.  send an alert if you don't hear from me in the next 20 minutes.
2022-12-29 17:00 i'm alive but inactive.  don't send an alert.
2022-12-29 17:10 i'm alive but inactive.  don't send an alert.
2022-12-29 17:20 i'm alive but inactive.  don't send an alert.
```

In this example, there should be an alert triggered at 16:40 and not earlier.  also, there should be no alert after 17:00.

Comment: Would another way of saying this be "I want to alert when I haven't seen a log message in the last 20 minutes but the message I saw before that was 'Alive and Kicking'"?

Comment: Step 1. You should write  log query to match the condition and test if you get right result. Step2. Create alert on it.

Comment: @Kolban it has to be the last message before that, not any preceding message.  there should be no alert at 17:40

Comment: @UmeshKumarSharma how can i write a log query to get the last message containing "alive" and check for the conditions of "inactive" OR less than 20 minutes ago?

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways if you wanna use a bit of coding and some external tools like n8n, I will describe both procedures in a simple way.

Using Cloud Run:

If you are a coding geek and like coding you can write a simple python or shell script for validating the timestamps and if the duration is 20 min and it matches your desired string values you can trigger an alert.

Save the logs in a cloud bucket -> use log based alerts or cron job to trigger your cloud run -> Python/shell script will match the string values and finds the diff in timestamps -> alert will be triggered by cloud run if the conditions are matched

Using N8N:

If you wanna use some workflow based tools or rpa tools with all kinds of regex filters and multiple integration options you can use n8n. This is a rpa tool which can be deployed in your environment on a container with minimal resources. This will help you to achieve self healing functionalities and there are many other use cases available online. The execution flow will go like this

Logs based alert triggers an event which triggers n8n webhook -> the webhook will update the data in a google sheet or csv file -> You can write a custom function to find the difference between timestamps -> if the conditions are met trigger another webhook for notifying in slack or for sending a mail etc…

```
from datetime import datetime

# start time
start_time = "2:13:57"
end_time = "11:46:38"

# convert time string to datetime
t1 = datetime.strptime(start_time, "%H:%M:%S")
print('Start time:', t1.time())

t2 = datetime.strptime(end_time, "%H:%M:%S")
print('End time:', t2.time())

# get difference
delta = t2 - t1

# time difference in seconds
print(f"Time difference is {delta.total_seconds()} seconds")

# time difference in milliseconds
ms = delta.total_seconds() * 1000
print(f"Time difference is {ms} milliseconds")
```

In n8n you can use regex for getting start time and end time.

Answer (score 0):

I would use multiple GCP services together to achieve this use case. This would include log-based alerts, Pub/Sub two Cloud Functions and Cloud Tasks.

- First setup [log-based alerts](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/alerting/log-based-alerts) and notification channel as [Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options).
- The [Pub/Sub will trigger](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub) a Cloud Function which will [push a task in the Cloud Task queue](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-http-target-tasks) which will trigger another Cloud Function after 20 minutes.
- In the second Cloud Function, check for the logs and the difference in their timestamps. If there are no logs in 20 minutes, trigger the alert.

I know this is quite complex and involves multiple GCP services but can't think of anything better for this use case. The catch here is, for any log which contains "alive and kicking", we need to check after 20 minutes if there are any other logs or not. If there are any other logs, we can ignore but if there are not any other logs, the alert should be triggered. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Or you can remove the Pub/Sub part by configuring the log-based alert's notification channel as webhook and give the URL of the first Cloud Function -> https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options#webhooks

Comment: can i have a 20 minute delay with the webhook?

Comment: Yes, in this case also, you'll need two cloud functions. First will be triggered right after the logs is present in cloud logging. This function will schedule another Cloud Function to run after 20 minutes using Cloud Tasks. The sencond Cliud function will check the logs and the timestamp. Based on it, it will trigger the alert.

Comment: Can it be done more simply with a periodic cloud function?

Comment: Yes, you can use cloud scheduler for this purpose. I have provided the reference [docs](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/tut-pub-sub) here